# Struct accessing to represent file name?

Tags: c, data-structures, macros, struct, io

Once I saw very interesting code, containing something like:

```
typedef struct
{
    FILE* txt;
    FILE* ini;
} PFILE;

int main(void)
{
    PFILE NEW_FILE;
    create_file (settings.txt); // creats file called settings.txt

    return 1;
}
```

What I might be missing are some arcane macros. This is just part of the code I don't remember.
Oh and obviously I'm missing that `create_file` function. Anyway I'm sure you get what I'm asking. How is that even possible?

Comment: to start, this line: PFILE NEW_FILE; should be struct PFILE NEW_FILE;

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

`create_file` is definitely a macro, that stringifies its argument with the `#` operator and calls `fopen()` (or a function that calls it) on it.

It could be defined as such:

```
#define create_file(x) NEW_FILE.txt = fopen(#x, "w")
```

Comment: Please, give me an example of how i could make that to work out. It appears that i also would need that in my current project. So not only curiosity.

Comment: The `#` operator? I only remember from books that is only used to declare preprocessor directive. And what if it is `settings.ini` i don't get it. Maybe i need to know about `#` to figure it out

Comment: @Edenia that's only at the beginning of a line. In the middle of a macro it becomes the "stringify" operator.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Interasting.